# Real and Imaginary part for particle polarisability

Tags: polarization, complex-numbers, dielectric

I am trying to determine the real and imaginary parts from the following equation for the polarisability of particles $\Lambda_{MG}(\lambda)$:

$$\Lambda_{MG}(\lambda) = \frac{\epsilon(\lambda) - \epsilon_{m}}{\epsilon(\lambda) + 2\epsilon_{m}}$$

with $\epsilon(\lambda)$ being the dielectric function that I elsewhere have the real and imaginary part for already and with $\epsilon_m$ the dielectric constant of the surrounding medium (assumed to be independent of wavelength). I do have a calculation, but I'm not sure if the way I'm doing it is correct at all. If anybody could hopefully tell me it's correct or tell me where I go wrong it would be greatly appreciated. I have the real and imaginary parts for $\epsilon(\lambda)$, so the first step I did was replace that with $x + yi$ in the above equation:

$$= \frac{x + yi - \epsilon_{m}}{x+yi + 2\epsilon_{m}}$$

multiply it with the conjugate $\frac{x-yi + 2\epsilon_{m}}{x-yi + 2\epsilon_{m}}$

$$=\frac{x + yi - \epsilon_{m}}{x+yi + 2\epsilon_{m}} \cdot \frac{x-yi + 2\epsilon_{m}}{x-yi + 2\epsilon_{m}}$$

$$=\frac{x^2 - xyi + 2x\epsilon_m + xyi -y^2i^2 + 2yi\epsilon_m -x\epsilon_m + yi\epsilon_m - 2{\epsilon_m}^2}{x^2 - xyi + 2x\epsilon_m + xyi -y^2i^2 + 2yi\epsilon_m + 2x\epsilon_m - 2yi\epsilon_m + 4{\epsilon_m}^2}$$

$$= \frac{x^2 + y^2 + x\epsilon_m + 3yi\epsilon_m - 2{\epsilon_m}^2}{x^2 + y^2 + 4x\epsilon_m + 4{\epsilon_m}^2}$$

Then for the real part take everything without an i and replace the x's with Re($\epsilon$) and y's with Im($\epsilon$)

$$\text{Re}(\Lambda) = \frac{\text{Re}(\epsilon)^2 + \text{Im}(\epsilon)^2  + \text{Re}(\epsilon)\epsilon_m - 2{\epsilon_m}^2}{\text{Re}(\epsilon)^2 + \text{Im}(\epsilon)^2 + 4\text{Re}(\epsilon)\epsilon_m + 4{\epsilon_m}^2}$$

and similarly for the imaginary part

$$\text{Im}(\Lambda) = \frac{3\text{Im}(\epsilon)\epsilon_m}{\text{Re}(\epsilon)^2 + \text{Im}(\epsilon)^2 + 4\text{Re}(\epsilon)\epsilon_m + 4{\epsilon_m}^2}$$

Are those correct?

Comment: Looks good to me, as long as $\epsilon_m$ is real.

Comment: Thank you very much!